# Smooth transition in IE9

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer

I am trying to achieve smooth transition in IE9.
Using below line of code,i could achieve this in Chrome.
    `$('.timeline').css("-webkit-transition", "-webkit-transform 0.2s");`

But, i couldn't find a way for IE9. After long research, i found that smooth transition is not possible in IE9. But smooth transition in below site is working fine when used with IE9.

http://codecanyon.net/item/content-timeline-jqueryhtml5css3-plugin/full_screen_preview/2617834

Is there anyway i can get the smooth transition working in IE9 version?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: IE9 doesn't support native CSS transitions (IE10 supports them fully, which is nice). Any transitions, therefore, are powered by JavaScript. In jQuery, this would probably be an appropriate use of `.animate()`, however personally I'd just forget it and use it as incentive for people to stop ignoring Windows Update when it tries to make their computer more secure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Niet the Dark Absol suggested, i used jQuery 'animate' to achieve this. Thank you 'Niet the Dark Absol'..